# Using personal keyboard in work profile (Shelter) on Android 10

Tags: applications, keyboard

I am using [Shelter](https://github.com/PeterCxy/Shelter) to create an isolated space for apps which I don't trust very much and to disable them when I am not using. Shelter works by creating a work profile in Android and registering itself as the administrator, thus granting it rights to disable apps.

This has been working great in my Android 8 phone, but I recently got a new phone which comes with Android 10, and unfortunately it looks like I can no longer share the same keyboard in work profile apps. This is important to me because I use [KeePass2Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android)
to store my passwords and it provides a virtual keyboard to automatically input credentials into any text field.

Is there any way to get back the old functionality and be able to use personal keyboards in work apps?

Comment: @beeshyams Shelter directly provides the option to install personal apps into the work profile, so I can use that, but it is a last resort since I would have to maintain two apps... not ideal :)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/PeterCxy/Shelter/issues/10 KeePass2Android does have the ability to cloud sync the database file, https://github.com/PhilippC/keepass2android/blob/master/docs/Documentation.md#opening-an-existing-database

Comment: @MorrisonChang The GitHub issue is slighty related, the user is trying to isolate the keyboard to a certain profile, which is the opposite of what I am trying to do :)

Comment: I just ran into the same issue: On Android 9 everything was great but now I have two separate keyboards, two sets of settings and six different dictionaries (for three languages each…). It really is beyond me how anyone could think this separation would be a good idea in 100% of the cases (i.e. without being able to switch it off).

Comment: @balu Indeed, I agree with you, there should have been an option to disable keyboard separation, it could be similar to the "one-lock" option we already have for the work profile.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ZeshanMunir No, I did not find any solution. I'm still using the only other viable alternative, which is to copy the data to clipboard.

Comment: @TheDcoder Gotcha! I am using Microsoft Swift Keyboard in both personal and work profiles and have same login in the keyboard, that syncs some of the stuff (no clipboard sharing though). Other alternative is to use Gboard and that has internal sync enabled across both profiles.

Comment: @ZeshanMunir How is Gboard able to do that? If it can do that, maybe other keyboards can too. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @TheDcoder On Android 13, Settings -> Apps -> Special App Access -> Connected Work & Personal Apps -> Choose App i.e. Gboard -> Enabled Connected Switch. That will enable the sync between both keyboards (also available for other apps i.e. Android Auto etc.)

Comment: @ZeshanMunir Holy crap... it might work for other keyboards too then!

Comment: I tried with SwiftKeyboard and it said "blocked by admin". Would you accept the above comment as answer?

Comment: @ZeshanMunir I have to try it first. "blocked by admin" could either mean the work profile owner or the device owner app itself. There are apps like Hail which can suspend apps in the main profile if you assign them as the device owner via ADB.

Comment: @TheDcoder I am almost certain that "blocked by admin" is actually blocked by Sheltor. Let me know what works best for you, I am going to post it as answer, we can discuss on that there.

Comment: @ZeshanMunir Thanks, I will try it soon and give you an update.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it working on Android 13:

*Settings -> Apps -> Special App Access -> Connected Work & Personal Apps -> Choose App i.e. Gboard -> Enabled Connected Switch. That will enable the sync between both keyboards (also available for other apps i.e. Android Auto etc.)*

[image]

Please note, I tried with SwiftKeyboard and it said "blocked by admin", I am almost certain that Shelter has some weird policy that is stopping it.

So as of now it works well with Gboard. Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Actually this can be done. In shelter in work profile tap "SwiftKey keyboard" and check "allow cross platform interaction" then go android settings > apps > special access > connected work and personal apps > chose SwiftKey > Enable connected switch.

Comment: @PatrykB What's the Shelter App's version where you have seen that option? I got Shelter v1.8 via F-Droid and that is latest there, I don't see this option in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Install your keyboard by cloning it into Shelter or by installing it through an App Store that is installed / cloned into Shelter.

After that, you can activate your keyboard in *Settings > System > Languages and input > On-screen keyboard > Work*.

The reason why Android enforces a separation on the keyboard is simple: Third party keyboards also grab data. If you choose to use a third-party keyboard, it should not be able to combine your data. Shelters goal is the strict split between your data to provide isolation and thus more privacy.

EDIT: This will not include data sharing which you're apparently after. It wasn't clear to me before you replied to me. If it's just about getting the "same keyboard" (in "same APK" without data sharing), this is the right approach.

**An alternate solution for your problem with KeePass**

I had the same problem, here is how I solved it:

I've setup Syncthing on all my profiles and my PC (should work with Shelter as well) and let all profiles sync a KeePass database. Use the Syncthing-Fork from F-Droid in particular, it offers better diagnostic capabilities. Alternatively, use another Cloud provider if privacy is not a concern.

I use KeePassDX from F-Droid on all my profiles. It allows to open a local KeyPass database and supports quick unlock with a PIN. It works well between profiles.

Good part about this solution is that your KeePass database is synced between two devices. It works with multiple Android user profiles and should also work with Shelter.

If this doesn't suit you, there is only the old copy paste between your KeePass app and the isolated Shelter app, because the clipboard is shared between both profiles.

Comment: This does not answer the question, I am aware that you can simply clone the keyboard and enable it there, but as you mentioned there is data separation, which is what I'm trying to avoid. In other words, I want to use the same 3rd-party keyboard even in the work profile and I don't care about isolation in that case because I trust the keyboard.

Comment: @TheDcoder Your question was a bit unclear to me then. "same keyboard" can also be interpreted as same APK, which would exclude data. I found your question, because I just wanted to know how to get the same keyboard without data sharing, found a solution and shared it trying to help. Maybe you could update your question to better reflect what your main goal is. Thanks for the downvote.